# When element uses click function it then ignore mouseleave

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use JQuery to show a character on mouseover but hide on mouseleave. However when the element is clicked I want the character to stay until another element is clicked. This works until an element is clicked off from and you mouseover it again. The mouseleave function no longer will work.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/z5v25yhL/

```
    $('.sidecategory').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $(this).next("span").show("fast");
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).next("span").hide("fast");
    },
    click: function(){
        $('.sidecategory').not(this).next("span").hide();
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're removing the `mouseleave` event each time an element is clicked:

```
$(this).off('mouseleave');
```

To avoid this, you could instead add a class to the element in order to select it.

Within the `mouseleave` event, exclude this `.selected` class, and then remove the `.selected` class from all elements when one is clicked. In doing so, you no longer need to remove the `mouseleave` event like you were doing before.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhdvzn4j/)

```
$('.sidecategory').on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $(this).next("span").show("fast");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).not('.selected').next("span").hide("fast");
    },
    click: function () {
        $('.sidecategory').removeClass('selected').not(this).next("span").hide();
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using classes it a better solution, but it can be done with on/off as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/z5v25yhL/1/

```
var selected;
var mleave = function () {
    $(this).next("span").hide("fast");
};

$('.sidecategory')
    .on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).next("span").show("fast");
    }).on('mouseleave', mleave).on('click', function () {
        if(selected) {
            $(selected).on('mouseleave', mleave);
            $(this).off('mouseleave');
            $('.sidecategory').not(this).next("span").hide();
        } else {
            $(this).off('mouseleave');
            $('.sidecategory').not(this).next("span").hide();            
        }
        selected = this;
    });
```